# npm install runs successfully but creates an empty node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

Whenever I run npm install, it shows that it's installing but nothing happens after and I'm left with an empty node_modules folder. This keeps occurring even when using the sudo command in the terminal. I've tried different solutions online but none seem to work. Here is my package.json file (using a mac running on Catalina).

```json
{
  "name": "pluralsight-project-build-an-album-store-product-page-with-angular",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs --recursive --reporter spec",
    "test:part2": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part2/ --recursive --reporter spec",
    "test:part3": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part3/ --recursive --reporter spec",
    "test:part4": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part4/ --recursive --reporter spec",
    "test:part5": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part5/ --recursive --reporter spec",
    "test:part6": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part6/ --recursive --reporter spec",
    "test:part7": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part7/ --recursive --reporter spec",
    "tutor-test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs --recursive --reporter json & ng test --config tutor-karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tutor-test:part2": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part2/ --recursive --reporter json & ng test --config tutor-karma.conf.js --single-run --part part2",
    "tutor-test:part3": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part3/ --recursive --reporter json & ng test --config tutor-karma.conf.js --single-run --part part3",
    "tutor-test:part4": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part4/ --recursive --reporter json & ng test --config tutor-karma.conf.js --single-run --part part4",
    "tutor-test:part5": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part5/ --recursive --reporter json & ng test --config tutor-karma.conf.js --single-run --part part5",
    "tutor-test:part6": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part6/ --recursive --reporter json & ng test --config tutor-karma.conf.js --single-run --part part6",
    "tutor-test:part7": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part7/ --recursive --reporter json & ng test --config tutor-karma.conf.js --single-run --part part7",
    "mocha-spec": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/ --reporter spec",
    "mocha-json": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/ --reporter json",
    "karma-spec": "ng test --config tutor-karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
    "@phenomnomnominal/tsquery": "2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.1",
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "cssom": "0.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "jasmine2-custom-message": "0.8.2",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-nightmare": "0.4.13",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-structured-json-reporter": "1.0.0",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "mocha": "3.4.2",
    "parse5": "5.1.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, look into the correct folder?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to run it from the project's root directory.

Comment: is your npm up to date? did you do "npm cache clean"

Comment: tried all those as well. No good. The weird thing is it only happens with this project in particular. All my other angular projects run fine.